# Intel c++ compiler access violation error at compile time

Tags: c++, intel-parallel-studio

I have a project that compiles both in Ubuntu and g++ 7.4 and Visual Studio 2019. However, when I use Visual Studio I am stuck with a really old OpenMP version (200203). I am trying the intel c++ compiler to see if using it I can compile the project using a newer version of OpenMP (5.0). My project is CMake-based and I configure it using the following command to compile using intel c++ compiler 19.0 in visual studio:

```
cmake [Various options to locate all libraries] .. -T "Intel C++ Compiler 19.0"
```

and then compile using

```
cmake --build . --config Release
```

which produces

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\include\pplwin.h(93): error: access violation [PATH TO MY PROJECT]
        static ::std::shared_ptr<scheduler_interface> * _S_scheduler_address;
                                                        ^
```

Any ideas on what might be happening? It's my first time getting an access violation error during compilation.

The same error happens with Debug builds.

PS: I am trying to get a MCVE that I can share but so far it has been impossible. This happens in a pretty large private-owned repository.

Comment: If your compiler is crashing submit a bug report to your compiler vendor

Comment: I also posted to [their forum](https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-c-compiler/topic/824977), but there has been not a single answer...

Comment: I think you should report to priority support instead of forum.

Comment: I am not a client yet (I am using the 30 days free trial), I am trying the compiler to see whether or not to become one.